# как сделать динамические параметры метода?

Tags: c++

не уверен что корректно задал вопрос,но суть вот в чем :

можно ли сделать вот что : ?

```
1 class additionToTheArea {
2     void addToTheArea( //some parametres ) {
3     //some code 
4 }
5
6 int main() {
7    Unit soldier;
8    Unit wizard;     (обьекты абстрактного класса юнит,но тут это не имеет роль)
9    Unit berserk;
10   Unit rogue;
11   
12   additionToTheArea add = new additionToTheArea(); //указатель на класс
13
14   add.addToTheArea(soldier, wizaerd, berserk, rogue);  <- здесь может быть больше чем 4 юнита!
15 }
```

вопрос :

как сделать во 2 строке,в параметрах метода так,чтобы я мог передавать столько юнитов(обьектов) в параметры метода,сколько захочу,и не будет ошибки,что я могу туда передать допустим только 2 обьекта.

пример:

ошибка будет если допустим :

```
void addToTheArea(Unit 1, Unit 2);

addToTheArea(Unit 1, Unit 2, Unit 3);
```

**БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ МАССИВА**

Comment: Например, используйте функцию с переменным числом аргументов — `addToTheArea(...)`. Или передавайте вектор. Но что-то меня смущает само наличие класса просто для добавления юнитов куда-то там...

Comment: аргументов может быть хоть 1000,я этого не могу знать

Comment: у меня там не маленький проект,так что был бы очень длинный вопрос.Так что я немного скоротил его @Harry

Comment: Ошибка архитектуры?

Comment: Решение - передавать вектор указателей. *"**БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ МАССИВА**"* **ПОЧЕМУ?**

Comment: @smth вам ответили в самом первом комментарии. Это именно то, что вам нужно, называется эллипсис

Comment: Кажется, `std::initializer_list<Unit>` подходит.